# FastAPI - @Schema(hidden=True) not working when trying to hide the schema section on swagger docs

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, fastapi

I'm trying to hide the entire schemas section of the FastAPI generated swagger docs. I've checked the docs and tried this but the schema section still shows.

```
    @Schema(hidden=True)
    class theSchema(BaseModel):
        category: str
```

How do I omit one particular schema or the entire schemas section from the returned swagger docs.

docExpansion does not appear to work either. What am I missing?

```
app = FastAPI(
    openapi_tags=tags_metadata,
    title="Documentation",
    description="API endpoints",
    version="0.1",
    docExpansion="None"
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

swagger has the UI parameter "defaultModelsExpandDepth" for controlling models' view in the schema section.

This parameter can be forwarded using "swagger_ui_parameters" parameter on FastApi initialization.

```
app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_parameters={"defaultModelsExpandDepth": -1})
```

Values:

- -1: schema section hidden
- 0: schema section is closed
- 1: schema section is open (default)

More options can be found here: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

Answer (score 10):

set `include_in_schema=False` in the args to the `FastAPI` instance decorator instead

```
app = FastAPI(...)

@app.get("/", include_in_schema=False)
async def root():
    ...
```

Comment: That removes the entire endpoint from the docs. I only want to remove the schema section

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get points for answering my own question but if anyone wants to know, this was resolved by loading the swagger page into an iframe then using js to hide the desired elements within that document's iframe.

Comment: that is not a very good approach, and you have to deploy the new html/js files as static and .... it's a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where I wanted to exclude certain schemas including "Enum" schemas as well. The only way I was able to do it was to generate custom OpenAPI schema as explained in [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/).

First, you use the "schema_extra" pydantic Model Config to add a hidden field in generated json. This can be found in [pydantic's documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/).

```py
class ModelA(BaseModel):
    Field1: int | None = None
    Field2: str | None = None


class Config:
    schema_extra = {"hidden": True}
```

Then you can generate the custom OpenAPI schema using,

```py
def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="My app",
        version="1.0",
        description="My app's description",
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    if "components" in openapi_schema:
        # I used jsonref to dereference related schemas
        # You will need to install jsonref
        dereferenced_schema = jsonref.loads(json.dumps(openapi_schema), lazy_load=False)
        openapi_schema["components"] = jsonable_encoder(dereferenced_schema["components"])
        for schema_name in openapi_schema["components"]["schemas"].copy().keys():
            schema = openapi_schema["components"]["schemas"][schema_name]
            if "enum" in schema:
                print(f"Removing {schema_name} as it is an enum")
                del openapi_schema["components"]["schemas"][schema_name]
                continue

            hide = schema.get("hidden", False)
            if hide:
                print(f"Removing {schema_name} as it is hidden")
                del openapi_schema["components"]["schemas"][schema_name]
                continue

    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema
```

Finally, assign this custom function to your FastAPI app's openapi funciton as-

```py
app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To omit a path from the schema, use the parameter `include_in_schema` and set it to `False`.

```py
@app.get("/items/", include_in_schema=False)
async def read_items()
```

You can read more about it [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/path-operation-advanced-configuration/).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**